# #define function arguments c++

Tags: c++

I have a set of functions called in a common interface, and I store those function pointers in a common container, so I have

```
typedef void(*CommandFunction)(const InputArgsMap &, const ArgumentMap *);
```

With this said, what is the best way to declare functions of this type without copy-pasting the argument list? I thought of implementing this via a `#define`, but is there any other (better, oop) way?

For instance, is it possible to do something like

```
#define CMD_ARGS (const InputArgsMap &, const ArgumentMap *)
void _fcn_1(CMD_ARGS);
void _fnc_2(CMD_ARGS);
```

Comment: Try it! Run through the preprocessor and see what it outputs.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That would tell you that you can't do it exactly like this. It won't tell you whether something like this might work.

Comment: Thank you for the answers :) it works, I jut had to remove the `()` in the `#define` directive.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to incorporate the answer

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's where the "see what it outputs" part comes in. It'll be quite clear that the parens need removing but that it'll otherwise work

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry, but that was not the answer, just one possibility which is also not 100% suitable and that is what I was referring to, that's why the question says 'it is possible to do something like'

Comment: @manatttta: I did not say it was the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare a function, rather than pointer, type alias

```
typedef void CommandFunction(const InputArgsMap &, const ArgumentMap *);
```

then you can use it to declare functions

```
CommandFunction _fcn_1;
CommandFunction _fcn_2;
```

You'll still need to write out the parameter list when you define them.

> is there any other (better, oop) way?

Overriding a virtual member function of an abstract interface might be nicer, depending on exactly what you're doing. You will have to duplicate the parameter list if you do that, which you seem to find distasteful; but in modern C++ you can at least use the `override` specifier to make sure you get that right.

Comment: Thank you! it effectively improves my syntax. I want to store function pointers in a container, that's why I defined directly as a pointer. However, I would also like to simplify the function declaration, i.e., `_fcn_1(args)`, if it were possible.

Comment: @manatttta: You still can write `CommandFunction*` to get a function pointer. As for `args`, you still need type and name for all of them. To avoid that, you'd need a macro `#define ARGS(a1, a2) InputArgsMap const& a1,  ArgumentMap const* a2`